# How to increase or decrease value in firebase by a percentage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can increase the value in firebase using this simple line of code:

```
dbRef.child("points").setValue(ServerValue.increment(1));
```

Or decrease:

```
dbRef.child("points").setValue(ServerValue.increment(-1));
```

This works very well, but now I want to increase by a random percentage like by 30%. What I mean is for example in Firebase there is a value of 100, and I want to increase that by 30%, to get 130 points. Instead of pushing the actual number I want to push 30%.

What I have tried is:

```
dbRef.child("points").setValue(ServerValue.increment(*1.30));
```

And I am getting error:

> Expression expected.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`ServerValue.increment` can only modify a value by the exact amount you specify.  It can't do relative amounts.  What you will have to do is read the child value, compute the final value in your code, and write the new value back.

Comment: I am actually avoiding that for certain reasons, 1 being: I have plenty of data to update on a single button click, so retrieving value first then do math and send the new value will not work well for my needs

Comment: That's really your only option though. Firebase doesn't support what you're trying to do here.